Only pure javacsript or css to make a button move with cursor
I have a button on an autoplay video that toggles sound on click. I would like to make the button move with the cursor within the video box while still clickable.
I tried the html, javascript below that moves the cursor but the button stays put. (note: This code is only showing the button and not the video or toggle sound functionality)
How can I make the button simply move with the cursor as well?
<body>

 <button class="magic-hover magic-hover__square">Toggle Sound</button>
 
 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/veseylab/raw/upload/v1684982764/magicmouse-2.0.0.cdn.min.js"></script>

<script>
 options = {
    "cursorOuter": "circle-basic",
    "hoverEffect": "circle-move",
    "hoverItemMove": false,
    "defaultCursor": true,
    "outerWidth": 40,
    "outerHeight": 40
      };
    magicMouse(options);
</script>

</body>

